# Using jquery_lazyload on Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, requirejs, lazyload

I tried to use [jquery_lazyload](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload) on Magento 2 & couldn't get it to work.
I loaded it using requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
deps: [
    "js/my_script"
],
paths: {
    "LazyLoad": "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lazyload@2.0.0-beta.2/lazyload"
},
shim: {
    'LazyLoad': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
};
```

> & then I added my_script.js

```
define(["jquery","LazyLoad"], function($) {
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function($) {
    let images = document.querySelectorAll(".lazyload");
    lazyload(images);
});
return;
});
```

> What I get is this error on console:

```
lazyload.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'settings' of undefined
at LazyLoad (lazyload.js:78)
at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
at Module.check (require.js:866)
at Module.enable (require.js:1143)
at Module.init (require.js:774)
at callGetModule (require.js:1170)
at Object.completeLoad (require.js:1544)
at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptLoad (require.js:1671)
```

> Update: The error occurs even when I'm not initializing the lazyload (something in the file itself breaks the requirejs).

---

**UPDATE (solved)**
It's working fine with the older version of lazyload (1.9.3), I got the error on v2.0.0. Still, I have no idea why it failed with the newer version though.

Comment: Try to call like `new LazyLoad(images);` instead of `layzyload(images)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> app/code/Ravindra/Modulename/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
            'lazyloadjs': 'Ravindra_Modulename/js/lazyload.js'
        },
    shim: {
        'lazyloadjs': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Tried that & got the same error.

Comment: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*

Comment: rm -rf var/cache/* generated/*

Comment: The error occures even when I'm not initializing the lazyload (something in the file itself breaks the requirejs).

Answer (score 0):

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
         'lazyload': "Vendor_Modulename/js/myfile"
      },   
    shim: {
    'lazyload': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
  }
}
```

**You can use anywhere in your template file by below method**

```
<srcipt>
 require(["jquery","lazyload"],function($,myfile){
     $(document).ready(function(){
        //call your js here...
     })
 })
</script>
```

Comment: Tried that & got the same error.